# How to run forEach on a promise?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a function returning a promise of array `async function functionReturningPromiseOfUserIDs(): Promise<string[]>`

Is it possible to run forEach on returning array?

```js
async function runForEachUser() {
   await functionReturningPromiseOfUserIDs().forEach((userID: string) => {
         return userID; // do stuff with userID
   }
}
```

Typescript says:

> Property 'forEach' does not exist on type '() =>
> Promise<string[]>'.ts(2339)

Comment: Change `await functionReturningPromiseOfUserIDs()` to `(await functionReturningPromiseOfUserIDs())`.

Comment: 1. it's `(await functionReturningPromiseOfUserIDs()).forEach(/* ... */)` 2. that's not going to help much because the `return` in the callback doesn't do anything.

Comment: @D.Pardal Would you please write it in answer form?

Comment: This should work: `const userIds = await functionReturningPromiseOfUserIDs(); userIds.forEach((id) => {
    // Do stuff with the id
  })`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write

```js
async function runForEachUser() {
   await functionReturningPromiseOfUserIDs().forEach((userID: string) => {
         return userID;
   });
}
```

Typescript thinks you're trying to call `.forEach()` on the *promise* returned by `functionReturningPromiseOfUserIDs()`. If you want to call `.forEach()` on the *value the promise resolves to*, use this:

```js
async function runForEachUser() {
   (await functionReturningPromiseOfUserIDs()).forEach((userID: string) => {
         return userID;
   });
}
```

Also, `.forEach()` ignores the return value of the callback.

Answer (score 1):

You need to await the Promise returned by functionReturningPromiseOfUserIDs(). If you update your first line to be this

`const userIds = await functionReturningPromiseOfUserIDs();`,

userIds will be the array of UserIds. Then you can simply use `userIds.forEach((id) => {})` to do what you want with them,